# Get the value from select box having custom attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Am having a select box that contains value attribute and custom value attribute, am confused about how could I get the value of the custom attribute and set it to the text box? Can anyone please help me to get this achieved?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <select class="class" id="someid" name="someName">
      <option data-othervalue=helloWorld value="some value">three</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="customValue">
  </form>
  <script>
    $('#country').change(function () {
       let data_othervalue  = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('custom-attr');
       let custom_value     = $('#data-othervalue').val(data_othervalue);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap the value in quotes.

Comment: ooh yup my mistake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 <option data-othervalue=hellow world value="some value">three</option>
```

to

```
 <option data-othervalue="hellow world" value="some value">three</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML isn't very strict with syntax and gives many possibilities to achieve one thing. One ways are better than the others and they are called as good practices.

Regarding you rquestion: attributes values can be specified without double-quotes as long as the value is string without any spaces, when space is introduced, browser reads only first word for attribute value, that's why you need to rap `hellow world` in double-quotes.

Having said that, good practice is to **always** use double quotes around the attribute values, no matter if they consist of one or more words.

Comment: @Alshoja If my answer helped, you can accept or/and upvote.

Comment: i had already given one answer as correct but i got the specific answer from barclick that is what i need :)